# How get Id when do upsert with flask_pymongo?

Tags: python, flask, pymongo

I want to get the document id, when I do and upsert, currently flask-pymongo only returns object Id when the document is inserted but not when is updated.

I am using the following code:

```
a = mongo.db.abcd.update_one(
    {'abcd': 'abcd1'}, {"$set": {"abcd": "abcd2"}}, upsert=True)

for value in a.raw_result.items():
    print(value)
```

There are any way to return the id?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`update_one()` returns a instance of `UpdateResult` (https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) and UpdateResult have a property `upserted_id`.

The documentation say: *The _id of the inserted document if an upsert took place. Otherwise None.*

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.UpdateResult.upserted_id

Looks like that is what you need